# Azure Automation Runbook export output/results to csv file

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation, azureportal, azure-runbook

Running the below code to get information on the Azure User we have in our AD using Automation runbook. Below is the code that i am using to get the Azure AD Users.

How can I save the Output from the runbook to a csv file ?

Please let me know if someone faces a similar issue or know how to solve it

```
# Get Azure Run As Connection Name
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
# Get the Service Principal connection details for the Connection name
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

# Logging in to Azure AD with Service Principal
"Logging in to Azure AD..."
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

"List Tenant Org Details:"
Get-AzureADTenantDetail | Select DisplayName, Street, PostalCode, City, CountryLetterCode


Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[a-j,A-J]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department

Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[k-t,K-T]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department

Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[u-z,U-Z]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
```

What changes should I make to my script that would allow me to save the output into a csv file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `export-csv` PowerShell cmdlet to export the PowerShell   cmdlet output to csv file .

Here is the common syntax for [export-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet :

```
Export-Csv [[-Path] <string>] [[-Delimiter] <char>] -InputObject <psobject> [-LiteralPath <string>] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-Encoding <string>] [-Append] [-NoTypeInformation] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

We have changed the above set of individual cmdlets(Get-AzureADuser -All $true) to below & added `-or` condition to them.

```
Get-AzureADUser | where-Object { {$_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[a-j,A-J]'} -or{ $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[k-t,K-T]'} -or { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[u-z,U-Z]'}} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department | Export-Csv C:\usersslist.csv
```

Here is the sample output for the above PowerShell cmdlet

[image]

Comment: How would I add the above export-csv into my azure automation script?

Comment: @BilalYousaf - Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cloudlojik/using-export-csv-in-azure-automation) which will give the complete information on exporting the output to csv file from azure automation runbook